# What is the difference between assert_select vs. css_select?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm solving a bug on a web app that has mixed protocols on some of the images. What I want to do is to select all the images for my test checking to see if my logic code turned the protocol into the appropriate http/https. I ran into these two helper methods for rails but I don't quite get the difference. They essentially seem to be doing the same thing.

All I want to do is select all the images from my web page and then make sure to see they either have http or https.

Should I do:

```
assert_select("img") do |attachments|
  assert_match /http:/, attachments
end

css_select("a img").each do |attachments|
  assert_match /http:/, attachments
end
```

Any thoughts? When should I use one over the other?

Comment: `assert_select` accept a `&block` (http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Assertions/SelectorAssertions/assert_select #show source) when `css_select` does not (http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Assertions/SelectorAssertions/css_select #show source): basically, the difference is (quoting Rails' source) The block can be used `[...] to allow nested assert_select, which can be nested several levels deep.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`css_select` does not accept a `&block`, just `*args` ([see documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Assertions/SelectorAssertions/css_select))

> css_select(*args) public

Quoting documentation:

> Select and return all matching elements.

---

`assert_select` accepts a `&block` as argument ([see documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Assertions/SelectorAssertions/assert_select)):

> assert_select(*args, &block) public

The `&block` argument is optional. Quoting the documentation about the `&block` part:

> When called with a block `assert_select` passes an array of selected elements to the block. Calling `assert_select` from the block, with no element specified, runs the assertion on the complete set of elements selected by the enclosing assertion. Alternatively the array may be iterated through so that `assert_select` can be called separately for each element.

---

**In other words**, `assert_select` allows you to do nested `assert_select`

```
assert_select "ol" do |elements| # example from doc
  elements.each do |element|
    assert_select element, "li", 4
  end
end
```

Whereas `css_select` cannot be nested:

```
# this is an equivalent of the example above
assert (css_select('ol>li').size == 4), 'There is not 4 <li> inside the <ol> !'
```